# Selenium ChromeDriver's methods get blocked after using ExecuteAsyncScript (waiting for result from JS)?

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Experiencing the Selenium driver, I have a strong feeling that this is ***too buggy*** and really hard to control. I'm not so sure if this is also the case for Java version, but here I'm talking about the .NET version (installed using nuget: `Selenium.WebDriver`).

I'm mimicking the case `ExecuteAsyncScript` will block for a time before returning some result from javascript. However ***its call is put on another thread*** which frees the current UI thread from blocking, like this:

```
//this helps mimic the blocking situation better
_driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
Task.Run(() => {
                _driver.ExecuteAsyncScript("");
               });
```

After that I cannot do many things (I've not tried all, but looks like everything) on the `_driver` instance (of `ChromeDriver`), really what I want here is just to shutdown/close/dispose the driver without it being blocked like this:

```
_driver.Quit();
```

However it will never (and cannot) be done, the call is just blocked forever. If it's on a UI thread, the UI will be freezed, if it's on a dedicated thread, nothing happens (but debugging shows that the call is always blocked making the thread never exit). So I ***cannot*** destroy the `_driver` instance in this scenario.

It's so ridiculous and rarely (if not meaning to say ***never***) encountered in any standard/originally-developed .NET library I've used. I know this .NET version of Selenium is just ported from a Java version, so looks like that's some kind of Java code quality? (I've experienced some kind of similar feeling when working with `NPOI` - another Java-to-.NET ported library but used for Excel handling, it's just so poorly designed, really).

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior, however you will have a problem even if it worked, `ExecuteAsyncScript` need the window which is disposed in `_driver.Quit();`, you will get `No such session`.

Comment: @Guy I will accept any exception (because I can just handle it gracefully), however it's strange that it's just blocked so I cannot do anything, really a head-ache.

Comment: @Guy could you please let me know which version you've tried? (of both selenium and chromedriver), Mine are `3.9.1` for `Selenium.WebDriver` and `2.35.0` for `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver`

Comment: just tried updating selenium to `3.14.0` and chrome driver to `2.41.0` (which is considered as compatible with the current Chrome browser version 68 installed on my computer), still the same locking issue.

Comment: I'm using Selenium 3.12.0 and ChromeDriver 2.31. I don't think it make any difference. The `No such session` is ignored, you can see it only in debug and the test will pass, however it won't finish its task.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the script you are trying to run? try to run an empty script `ExecuteAsyncScript("")`, it will throw an error eventually but it should get out of the task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183167/discussion-between-guy-and-hopeless).